# please help me, what this mean? this happend when i want to install microsoft egde in linux terminal

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, software-center

```
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (type)
N: Ignoring file 'microsoft-edge-stable.list1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-stable.list ([option] not assignment)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (type)
N: Ignoring file 'microsoft-edge-stable.list1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-stable.list ([option] not assignment)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: 1) Microsoft is a company. How can you install it in the terminal? Edit your title to clarify it. 2) Remove the unusefull "Please help me, what this mean": this does not help in any way to see what the question will be about. 3) Format terminal code as code. Your best chance of having good ansers is to have a well composed, concise and clear question. Use "edit"  to improve your question.

Comment: so sorry i mean microsoft egde

Comment: It means that you did not follow the install instructions carefully enough. Fix the mistake(s) you made in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-stable.list`. Also clean up the other mistake you made with `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-stable.list1`. Pro Tip: When you make a mistake, clean it up before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says: the filename of the additional file under **/etc/apt/sources.list.d** is wrong. It needs to have the suffix **.list** not **.list1** like in your case.
Renaming the file correctly will resolve this problem.

Comment: This addresses the *informational* message (`N:`) but not the actual errors (`E:`)